# How animate Opacity in Flatlist with 2 columns

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

I try to make a little opacity animation when items touch the top of the flatlist.
The problem is that just one item rendered with the animation and not 2 Items at the same row.
I want that as soon as the top of these two Items touch the top of the Flatlistview, the opacity decrease until two others Items's top below. And so on.

I put my code here if anyone has some solution for that.

Thank you !

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet,Dimensions, Button, Pressable, TouchableOpacity, SafeAreaView, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, Switch,Image,FlatList, Animated } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Data_hobbys from '../../Data_hobbys';
import { TextInput,ProgressBar , Colors } from 'react-native-paper';

const DATA = Data_hobbys;

const numColumns = 2;

const { height } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const Item = ({ title, path, opacity }) => (
    
        <Animated.View style = {[styles.item, {opacity: opacity}]}>
            <Image style = {styles.imageStyle} source = {path}/>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
    
);


const Sports_selection = () => {

    const scrollY = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current

    const renderItem = ({ item, index}) => {

        const opacityInputRange = [
            -1,
            0,
            150 * index,
            150 * (index + 1)
        ]

        const opacity = scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: opacityInputRange,
            outputRange: [1 ,1 ,1 ,0]
        })

        return (<Item title={item.title} path = {item.path} opacity = {opacity} />
        
        );
    }
    return(

        <View style = {styles.main_container}>
            <ProgressBar progress={0.4} style = {styles.progressBar} color = '#D1A552'/>

            <Text style = {styles.introduction_text}>Do you some sport or watch it ?</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.instruction_text}>Yes ? Great select it !</Text>

       
            <Animated.FlatList
                onScroll = {Animated.event(
                    [{ nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: scrollY}}}],
                    {useNativeDriver: true}
                )}
                //contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection : "row", flexWrap : "wrap"}}
                columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}
                data = {DATA}
                renderItem = {renderItem}
                keyExtractor = {(item, index) => item.id}
                numColumns = {numColumns}
                style={{
                    height: "60%",
                    flexGrow: 0
                  }}
                //xscrollEventThrottle={16}
                style = {styles.flatlistStyle}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonNext}>
                <Text style = {styles.TextButton}>Next</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        
    );
}

export default Sports_selection;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main_container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    introduction_text: {
        fontSize : 30,
        fontWeight : 'bold',
        color : '#D1A552',
        textAlign : 'left',
        paddingLeft: 15,
        marginTop: '30%',
    },
    instruction_text: {
        fontSize : 20,
        fontWeight : 'normal',
        color : 'black',
        textAlign : 'left',
        paddingLeft: 15,
        marginTop: '2%',
    },
    item: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent:'center',
        height : 150,
        width : 150,
        marginVertical: 5,
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight : 'normal',
        paddingTop: 12,
        fontSize: 15,
        textAlign:'center',
    },
    imageStyle:{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    },
    flatlistStyle:{ 
        marginTop:'6%',
        height: "50%",
        flexGrow: 0,
    },
    buttonNext:{
        position: 'absolute',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "#D1A552",
        borderRadius: 30,
        width: "40%",
        height: 45,
        justifyContent: "center",
        bottom: "10%",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    TextButton:{
        fontWeight : 'bold',
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign:'center',
    },
    progressBar: {
        top: 70,
        width: "70%",
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to calculate the scrollY with high of item

```
const HIGHT_OF_ITEM=100
const HIGHT_OF_CONTAINER=HIGHT_OF_ITEM+20

const Sports_selection = () => {
  
  const scrollY = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {

  const input_cal=(value)=>{
     return value + HIGHT_OF_CONTAINER*(Math.floor(index/numColumns))
  }
    const opacityInputRange = [ input_cal(0), input_cal(50), input_cal(80),input_cal(100) ];

    const opacity = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: opacityInputRange,
      outputRange: [1,0.5,0.3,0]
      , extrapolate:'clamp'
    });

    return <Item title={item.title} path={item.path} opacity={opacity} />;
  };
```

[snack demo](https://snack.expo.dev/ciY782KjoM)